# How to write all javascript/Jquery exceptions to one text file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception, logging, error-handling

I want to log/write all javascript errors to one text file when ever an error happens in my JavaScript functions or jQuery plugins.

For eg. PHP page call fails, undefined var.. etc. like errors happens I need to write it on a text file.

How can I do that. Please help me.

Comment: You can use try...catch block in Javascript, but it is not exactly throwing exception like in Java...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependes on witch browser you are using:

```
> Firefox? - Look at firebug http://getfirebug.com/
> Chorme? - Right Click > Inspect element
> Safari? - Preferences > Advanced > Show develop menu in menu bar
> IE? - To complicated download another browser. :)
```

And then use `console.log(...);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use **console.log** for logging after installing **firebug**
https://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I get errors in javascript I make a call to my "LogError" function which passes the error data to a web service which can then log it on the server or email it off or whatever you need.